# ASP.NET Action Execute with PathBase

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have Asp.net core(running on .net framework) web mvc application.

**Startup.cs:**

```
public class Startup
  {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
      Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      var aiOptions = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
      {
        EnableQuickPulseMetricStream = true
      };
      services.AddMvc();
      services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions);
      services.AddCors(option =>
      {
        option.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin", policy => policy.WithOrigins("*"));
        option.AddPolicy("AllowGetMethod", policy => policy.WithMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"));
      });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
      TelemetryClient tc = new TelemetryClient();
      tc.TrackTrace("Environment: " + env);

      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        tc.TrackTrace("Development");
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }
      else
      {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }
      app.Use((context, next) =>
      {
        context.Request.PathBase = new PathString("/Application1");
        return next.Invoke();
      });
      app.UseStaticFiles();
      app.UseCors(select => select.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin());
      
      app.UseMvc(routes =>
      {
        routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "default",
                  template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                  name: "spa-fallback",
                  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
      });
    }
  }
```

**HomeController Action:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
  {
  public HomeController(StatelessServiceContext context){
  }
  public IActionResult UsernameAuthentication()
    {
      return View();
    }
  }
```

**Action Executing:**

> http://localhost:9040/Home/UserNameAuthentication

**Action not Executing:**

> http://localhost:9040/Application1/Home/UserNameAuthentication

Any other configuration i have to do,to execute Action with PathBase?or any other way to use context path to execute action.How?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try it with ``app.UsePathBase("/Application1");`` instead of ``app.Use((context, next) =>
      {
        context.Request.PathBase = new PathString("/Application1");
        return next.Invoke();
      });`` it is working in my case

Comment: @r08 any update? Does my reply help you?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you use `Application1/Home/UserNameAuthentication` as the url pass to the application, the application context.Request.Path will be the  `Application1/Home/UserNameAuthentication` then you add the pathbase, it will be `Application1/Application1/Home/UserNameAuthentication` this is the reason why you get 404 error.

To solve this issue, you should check whether the beginning of this Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString matches the specified Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
        app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            string _pathBase = "/Application1";
            PathString matchedPath;
            PathString remainingPath;

            if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(_pathBase, out matchedPath, out remainingPath))
            {
                var originalPath = context.Request.Path;
                var originalPathBase = context.Request.PathBase;
                context.Request.Path = remainingPath;
                context.Request.PathBase = originalPathBase.Add(matchedPath);
                var re = context.Request.PathBase;
                return next.Invoke();

            }
            else
            {
                return next.Invoke();
            }
        });
```

Result:

[image]